# finding velocity of a leaking object in motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, word-problem

I am having issue with my working for the problem displayed below.

[image]

Here are my working as follows

The questions ask for newtons second law, now as the mass varys with time I use the momentum form and use the product rule like so.

$$F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}=v\frac{dm}{dt}+m\frac{dv}{dt}$$

the equation what has been giving in the first equation

$$\alpha \frac{t}{T}=v\frac{dm}{dt}+m\frac{dv}{dt}$$

next I made the relevant substitutions for $$\frac{dm}{dt}=-2M_w\frac{t}{T^2}$$ and $$m(t)=M_g+M_w-M_w\frac{t^2}{T^2}=\frac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}{T^2}$$

and rearranged and equated in the following way

$$\frac{T\alpha t + 2M_wtV}{T^2}=\big(\frac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}{T^2}\big)\frac{dv}{dt}$$

Simplifying through and separating the variable I form the following integrals.

$$\int_0^t \frac{t}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}=\int_{v_0}^v \frac{1}{T\alpha 2M_wV}$$

Now I will omit every step I did for the integrals and outline what i did and the final solution.

LHS: I used U substitution to simplify the integral and formed the following solution.

$$-\frac{1}{2M_w} ln\big(\frac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2}\big)$$

RHS: I also did U substitution and formed the following equation.

$$\frac{1}{2M_w}ln\big( \frac{T\alpha+2M_wV}{T\alpha+2M_wV_0}\big)$$

Now if I equate the RHS with the LHS

$$-\frac{1}{2M_w}\big(\frac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2}\big)=\frac{1}{2M_w}\big( \frac{T\alpha+2M_wV}{T\alpha+2M_wV_0}\big)$$

simplyfying through

$$-\big(\frac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2}\big)=\big( \frac{T\alpha+2M_wV}{T\alpha+2M_wV_0}\big)$$

Now this is where my issue lies. Before I sub in the limits given I wanted to check if my equation made sense. So if I set $t=0$ I should get $V=V_0$ but this is not the case.

$$-(T\alpha + 2M_wV_0=T\alpha+2M_wV)$$

as you can see this is not what should be expected at t=0 if there was no '-' then it would be correct however I dont think the integration of the given equations is the issue here. It I believe it something at the beginning I have missed. But what I do not know.

I cant see how not using momentum is incorrect in this case as you have to take into account the varying mass with the water. I seem to not see another way of approaching this problem, could anyone shed light on my issue?

Comment: On your last step before omitting your work, you have $$\int_{v_0}^v\dfrac{1}{T\alpha 2M_wv}dv$$ but it should be $$\int_{v_0}^v\dfrac{1}{T\alpha + 2M_wv}dv$$

It looks like just a typo because your result shows that you had it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies with your integration over $t$

$$\int_0^t \frac{t}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}dt$$

Let $u=t^2$ such that $du=2tdt$. Now we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t \frac{t}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2}dt &= \dfrac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wu}du
\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2M_w}\ln|M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wu|
\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2M_w}\ln|M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2|\Bigg|_0^t
\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2M_w}\ln|M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2| + \dfrac{1}{2M_w}\ln|M_gT^2+M_wT^2|
\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2M_w}\ln\Bigg|\dfrac{M_gT^2+M_wT^2}{M_gT^2+M_wT^2-M_wt^2 }\Bigg|  
\end{align}$$

See it now?

Your way would've worked, but **when you "got rid of" the logarithms**, you were not careful enough about the negative sign. You carried it through although it should've inverted one of the two sides.

> $$-\ln|x|=\ln|x^{-1}|=\ln\Bigg|\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigg|$$

Comment: Yes, I do see my mistake, turns out it the integral. Thank you once again